# Assign a Folder # to a user

Tags: contacts

I'm looking to set up a membership for a concert band. Each member is assigned a folder number (2 digits plus an instrument name such as Flute 2). I'm too new at this to see how to set this up. Could someone please point me in the right direction?
Cheers, DHDa

Comment: Could you please give more information as to the platform (i.e. Drupal, Joomla, Wordpress) you are using, the version of CiviCRM, how your records are organised at the moment and what you are trying to achieve.  Have you investigated setting up CiviCRM using the User and Admin Guide at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/

Comment: Do you want Civi to assign the folder numbers based on some rules you define, or just to record the folder number assigned by something/someone else?  If it's just to record the numbers, that is easily done by adding [custom fields](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/)

Comment: This is a Joomla installation. The records aren't organized at present! We have 75 users (using the default entry method) but would like to move all our user information into here. The folder numbers are assigned by me when a folder is given out, but I want to be able to generate reports showing the user's name and folder number.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have already imported all your members into Joomla and Civicrm.

It seems to me that you will need at least 2 new custom fields named say 'folder number' and 'instrument name' into which you will make manual entries, and a new dataset (perhaps called 'Membership Information'). The newly created custom fields would then need to be added to either a new or existing profile.

You would be advised to read the custom fields documentation at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/ and profiles at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/profiles/

Hope this helps.